# Linux socket UDP server - exchanging messages between 2 servers on 2 machines

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, server

I am working on a small linux socket project. The goal is to have multiple servers (ie. 1,2,3,4,5) that listen for `send` `get` and `ACK` packets from each of their respective clients. I am currently attempting to implement a routing table protocol whereby 2 servers (A, B) exchange their routing tables (vectors containing respective clients, server name, and number of hops). The issue I am having is with binding a socket to B's external address from A and vice-versa. From what I have read you do not bind to anything other than a local address except in certain cases. What I am wondering is how do I simply fire off a UDP packet from one server to another knowing the (static) IP address of each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am wondering is how do I simply fire off a UDP packet from one
>   server to another knowing the (static) IP address of each server?

The short answer is, you can't.  At least on the Internet proper, only unicast is widely supported, which means that in order to send a UDP packet to another machine, you'll need to know its IP address (somehow).

The longer answer is:  The first thing you often need to do is discover the target machines' IP addresses.  That might be a matter of having the user manually enter a list of IP addresses, or if the target machines are on the same LAN, you can program a mechanism for auto-discovering them by having your program send out a broadcast or multicast UDP query packet.  Make sure any instances of your program running on the same LAN receive that packet and respond to it by sending back a response UDP packet (the responses can be sent by by unicast or multicast or broadcast, your choice), and then your query-originating computer can know from the responses it receives which other IP addresses your program is presently also running on.

Note that a lot of computers and network devices run firewalls that reject incoming UDP packets by default, so if you packets don't seem to be getting through that is a likely reason why.

Comment: Ahh I see. I do know the IP addresses of all servers but your answer gives a broader description of multiple ways to accomplish this. Thank you.